# How can a Wi-Fi Direct connection and network connection exist simultaneously?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct

To my understanding, you cannot connect to two Wi-Fi networks at the same time.  How is it possible then that an Android device can connect to a network and a Wi-Fi Direct group at the same time?

In other words, what is technically different about connecting to two Wi-Fi networks as opposed to a Wi-Fi direct group and a Wi-Fi network?

Answer (score 0):

All devices certified under the Wi-Fi Direct program allow the user to connect to an infrastructure or a Wi-Fi Direct-certified network. Some devices certified under the Wi-Fi Direct program support connections to both an infrastructure network and Wi-Fi Direct-certified group at the same time (e.g. a laptop may support an infrastructure connection while also belonging to a Wi-Fi Direct-certified group). Simultaneous connection to a Wi-Fi Direct-certified group and an infrastructure network is an optional feature.